# How many “linkage shapes” in the plane have $n$ “joints”?

Tags: homotopy-theory, plane-geometry

A **linkage shape** in the plane with $n$ **joints** means a choice of $n$ points (a.k.a., vertices) in the plane joined by struts (a.k.a., edges). The joints are flexible pivots for the struts connecting them. The rules for a linkage shape are: (1) the struts are connected end to end to form a closed path (a.k.a., cycle); (2) no joint can be straightened; (3) no two struts can intersect (except at their joints); (4) struts can be expanded or contracted in length (but never length 0). Two linkage shapes with $n$ joints are considered **equivalent** if either one can be obtained by continuous motion from the other by (a) changing angles at joints, or by (b) changing strut lengths, or by (c) translation or rotation (not reflection), all the while during the motion adhering to rules (1)-(4). I believe there are exactly 8 linkage shape equivalence classes with $6$ struts. In general, how many equivalence classes of linkage shapes with $n$ joints are there? (At a hardware store one may get a "folding ruler" for experiments with linkage shapes.)

Comment: In the literature, your linkage shapes in one equivalence class are called *non-crossing morphs* of one another. For example: Gotsman, Craig, and Vitaly Surazhsky. "Guaranteed intersection-free polygon morphing." *Computers & Graphics* 25, no. 1 (2001): 67-75. [PDF dowload](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~gotsman/AmendedPubl/GuaranteedIntersection/GuaranteedIntersection.pdf).

Comment: What are your counts to $n=3,4,5$? Clearly there is just one polygon triangle. $n=4,5$?

Comment: Many thanks for the reference. Yes, for n=3 there is 1; for n=4 there are 2; for n=5 there are 4; for n=6 there are 8. These were calculated by pencil and paper drawings. For n=7 and 8 there are computer simulations which currently lead me to believe there are 10 and 16 respectively, but those are not certain.

Comment: $1,2,4,8,10,16$ is not yet enough to pinpoint in OEIS...

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. I am revamping my simulations to get a longer (and possibly provably more reliable) sequence of counts.